# Notification for HTTP POST

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I am new to Spring framework and have tried creating an api for others to use.

This is in my controller class

**POST method**

```
 // -------------------Create a Report-------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/report/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createReport(@RequestBody Report report, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    logger.info("Creating Report : {}", report);

    if (reportRepository.isReportExist(report)) {
        logger.error("Unable to create. A report with name {} already exist", report.getCrisisID());
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to create. A Report with crisisID " + 
        report.getCrisisID() + " already exist."),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    reportRepository.saveReport(report);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/report/{crisisID}").buildAndExpand(report.getCrisisID()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**GET Method**

```
// -------------------Retrieve All Reports---------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/report/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Report>> listAllReports() {
    List<Report> reports = reportRepository.findAllReports();
    if (reports.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Report>>(reports, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below is the an example code for others to create the report object and send it to my api.

```
// POST 
    private static void createReport() {
    System.out.println("Testing create Report API----------");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Report report = new Report(20, "General", 4, "AA1",10000,"crisis details", "1 hour", "COA1", "COA1");
    URI uri = restTemplate.postForLocation(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/report/", report,
            Report.class);System.out.println("Location : "+uri.toASCIIString());
    }
```

I am wondering if the following is possible or if there is any way to approach this situation:

- When someone creates a report and sends it to me via POST URL, my POST method will be able to automatically detect that a new report entry is created and then sends a notification in my HTML/JSP page (such as a pop up window).

**Update**

RestApiController.java

```
   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApiController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApiController.class);

    @Autowired
    ReportRepository reportRepository; //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work


    // -------------------Create a Report-------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/report/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @SendTo("/channel/publicreport")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createReport(@RequestBody Report report, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        logger.info("Creating Report : {}", report);

        if (reportRepository.isReportExist(report)) {
            logger.error("Unable to create. A report with name {} already exist", report.getCrisisID());
            return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to create. A Report with crisisID " + 
            report.getCrisisID() + " already exist."),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        reportRepository.saveReport(report);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/api/report/{crisisID}").buildAndExpand(report.getCrisisID()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

WebSocketConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/chatservice");
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
            registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
            registry.enableSimpleBroker("/channel");
        }
    }
```

main.js

```
    'use strict';

var stompClient = null;
var username = null;

function connectReport(event) {
    username = "myname";

    if(username) {

        //var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
        //stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:8080/chatservice');

        stompClient.connect({}, onConnectedReport, onError);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}

function onConnectedReport() {
    // Subscribe to the Public Channel
    stompClient.subscribe('/channel/publicreport',onReportMessageReceived);
}
function onError(error) {
    connectingElement.textContent = 'Could not connect to WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try again!';
    connectingElement.style.color = 'red';
}
function onReportMessageReceived(payload) {
//Code for pop up window
}
window.addEventListener("load", connectReport, true)
```

Comment: Fist you need to choose an approach. Each with advantages/disadvantages: Option1. HTML keeps pooling the results. Option2. Use websockets.

Comment: If websocket is used, the notification will be real time but is not the case for continuous pooling rite?

Comment: correct. Also pooling is simpler to implement but may add extra load on the sever side

Comment: Do you know how/are you able to add STOMP websocket to work with my code above? I tried doing it but have no luck succeeding so far.

Comment: Lots of tutorials out there. II would start here: https://jansipke.nl/websocket-tutorial-with-java-server-jetty-and-javascript-client/

Comment: Do you mind looking at my current code and determine where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In general taks like this is delegated to client. I.e. client polls the server for the changes it is interested in and once detected the client reacts accordingly. The oldest way (which is now absolete) was to add a tag into HTML that forces the entire page to refresh with a certain frequency which means the page sends a request to the server and receives an updated page to display. IN our days there are all kinds of frameworks that do partial updates to the page. One of the first ones was Ajax, then DHTML and so on and so forth. I am not a client side progrqammer. But as far as the concept goes such task is usually given to client